# Equality of two sigma algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Can someone check my proof? I'm trying to prove this statement:

Let $f : E \rightarrow F$, define $\sigma: \mathcal P(F) \to \mathcal P(F)$ through:
$$\sigma(\varepsilon) = \bigcap_{B \supset \varepsilon} B \tag*{(where the Bs are $\sigma$-algebras)}$$
That is, $\sigma(\varepsilon)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\mathcal P(F)$ containing $\varepsilon$.
Then:
$$f^{-1}(\sigma(\varepsilon)) = \sigma(f^{-1}(\varepsilon))$$
That is $\sigma$ commutes with $f^{-1}$.

My attempt:
$$f^{-1}(\sigma(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon})) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{B \supset\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} } B \right)= \bigcap_{B \supset \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}} f^{-1}(B)=\sigma(f^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}))$$
Because $f^{-1}(B)$ are $\sigma$-algebras containing $f^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon})$.
Is this proof valid?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/preimage-of-generated-sigma-algebra

Comment: @Math1000 i asked if what i wrote is enough or nonsense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the commutation of smallest sigma-algebra and inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539411/prove-the-commutation-of-smallest-sigma-algebra-and-inverse)

Comment: @Snoop im asking to proof check, not give me an alternative proof

Comment: @HellBoy you can look at the posted references for valid proofs

Comment: @Snoop i saw them i dont want those, i want someone to check the validity of mine

Comment: It looks fishy. You are saying that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f^{-1}(\epsilon)$ (a subset of $E$) is found by interesecting $f^{-1}(B_i)$ when $B_i$ runs over $\sigma$-algebras in $F\,.$ Never seen such a proof. Case closed.

Comment: @KurtG. yes because $f^{-1}(B_i)$ are $\sigma$-algebras containing $f^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\epsilon})$ you can recheck the definitions of $\sigma(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon})$

Comment: But they are not *all* such $\sigma$-algebras :)

Comment: @KurtG. wym not all sigma algebras?, each $B_i$ is a sigma algebra containing $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ and an earlier lemma said that for any sigma algebra B over F, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is a sigma algebra over E

Comment: To find $\sigma(f^{-1}(\epsilon))$ we have to intersect *all* $\sigma$-algebras in $E$ that contain $f^{-1}(\epsilon)\,.$ Over to you. If you show that any $\sigma$-algebra we need to intersect here is of the form $f^{-1}(B_i)$ I will give in.

Comment: @KurtG. i literally just did, why do you fail to see that $f^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) \subset f^{-1}(B_i)$

Comment: I don't fail to see that. My point is that in $\bigcap_{\epsilon\subset B_i}$ the collection of $\sigma$-algebras over which you take that intersection is not what one expects.

Comment: i fail to see why that doesnt give us whats expected @KurtG.

Comment: If you say so. As I said: case closed.